# Infinite loop with selenium implicit wait java

Tags: java, selenium, testing

I'm testing the discord website, but when change the route, the test fail. I'm trying use implicit wait, but i'm getting a infinit loop.
(using selenium 3.5.3)

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "drivers/chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver navegador = new ChromeDriver();

navegador.get("https://discord.com/");
navegador.findElement(By.className("button-ZGMevK")).click();
navegador.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
navegador.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("mail@mail.com");
navegador.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("password");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go to the login page, why not change your url directly to login?

Like this https://discord.com/login :

```
navegador.get("https://discord.com/login");
navegador.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
navegador.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("mail@mail.com");
navegador.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("password");
```

But if you still want to click the login button first, change this line :

```
navegador.findElement(By.className("button-ZGMevK")).click();
```

To be:

```
navegador.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.appButton-2_tWQ1 > a[href*=login]")).click();
```